# This isn't a duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

I asked a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/57144/11762) recently about synonyms that appear to be antonyms, and whether there is a specific name for such word pairs. It was closed as a duplicate of a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1578/11762) asking *why* such words are not opposites. My question does not address the same issue at all; in fact it is based on the fact that they mean the same thing. Hardly an "exact duplicate" (at least in my opinion).

Comment: OK..I changed my mind. voted to reopen.

Comment: I voted to close, and I don't think I'll be reversing that. Imho, if there was a generally accepted name specifically identifying such *"superficially antonyms, but actually synonyms"* word-pairs, it would have been identified in the context of the earlier question. If OP is still hopeful, he could always edit his question to clarify the exact thing he's after, but so far as I'm concerned re-opening the second question will simply encourage people to either re-answer the first or pointlessly suggest unauthoritative coinages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought I made it fairly clear - what changes would you suggest to make it more so?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Even if there *is* such a term as you seek, I don't think ELU should be cluttered up with questions that "overlap" to such a degree. So I'm not suggesting you should edit your question so as to get it reopened - it's already "back in the frame" by virtue of you raising the matter here, plus it would jump to the top of the "active questions" list if you edited it. I don't expect to win this argument, since you've already got three reopen votes, but I stand by my opinion (and justification thereof) that reopening would not be in the best interests of the site overall.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: eh? Cluttered up? Overlapping? If you don't like a question, by all means vote it down, but please stop gratuitously closing perfectly acceptable questions for your own made-up reasons.

Comment: @Martha: We've been here before. I make my choices and you make yours. I'm only one voice here, same as anyone else - if you don't like my choices then you're free to disagree with me but please stop being gratuitously insulting towards me.

Comment: @Martha: I suggest that you say to (at)FumbleFingers what he said to me (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57358/idiom-about-tackling-smaller-problems-instead-of-tackling-the-root/57379#comment110021_57379): “actually, I thought it was just a good-natured discussion, but there you go! :)”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been reopened.

Comment: Okay, I'll take my shots! But damned if I'm gonna upvote this answer! :)

Comment: I completely agree with @Martha, and have up-voted both the question and this answer.