# Duplicate question, but original doesn't exist

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

(Based on "[How to challenge a duplicate closing](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7049/how-to-challenge-a-duplicate-closing?cb=1)," it seems posting a query here is how to do it...)

["How to pronounce letter “e” in new invented brand names? (in fictional words)"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167713/how-to-pronounce-letter-e-in-new-invented-brand-names-in-fictional-words?rq=1) is merged as it is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167648/how-to-pronounce-letter-e-in-new-invented-brand-names-in-fictional-words) -- which it is -- but the original question doesn't exist:  "page not found."

Since the original doesn't exist, shouldn't we re-open the new one?

Comment: The original was deleted by its owner, and was itself marked as a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77116/any-rule-for-pronouncing-e

Answer (score 6):

Well spotted. I have closed the question as a duplicate of the one Mr. Shiny and New lank to. ([Any rule  for pronouncing “e”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77116/any-rule-for-pronouncing-e))

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'lank' (simple past)?  E.g.  drink, drank, drunk; ring, rang, rung; sink, sank, sunk ---> link, lank, lunk.

Comment: Well spotted! I've fixed it

Comment: @chaslyfromUK your suggestion made me blink, blank, blunk.  Is that  irony or do you truly think, thank, thunk so?

Comment: chastly was teasing I believe, as he is from the UK he would know that *lank* is not correct. It should be *linked* and in this case 'and the new linked to' adding the 'the'. Hugo was attempting to point that out in a humorous fashion and it was funny, but that could be lost on someone learning the language. So that's why I wanted to make sure you got the correct usage.

Comment: I think Matt is also in on the joke; he is a moderator on the site and despite the use of Cyrillic characters in his name, his profile states that "British English is [his] native language."

Comment: Ha! "Lank", I'm laughing so hard I can't see straight.

Comment: I accidentally chank a chink in my cup, and now all I’ve got is this chunk of porcelain…